# using partials in view helpers

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, zend-framework, html-helper

Creating custom Zend View helpers I often end up with something like:

```
// logic here
if ($condition) {
    $output = <<<EOS...
} else {
    $output = <<<EOS...
}
```

or using `switch`.

Then to eliminate this, I create `setPartial()`, `getPartial()` and `htmlize()` for using external .phtml's.

This is not the best solution, because partials do not support doctype changing.

- Is there any better solution, than creating abstract class handling this common case?
- Are there any ready Zend solutions for this case?
- Separate view helper for each case? And where to put common code?

Comment: what do you mean under doctype changing? you want to change the doctype from the view helper?

Comment: When I change doctype anywhere in the app (in most cases in application.ini), helpers generating markup should change their behavior to produce code valid against this doctype. The helpers shipped with ZF are doctype independent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with view helpers (using services) and rendering the partials inside helpers.

There is an option to have logic in partials too, but in the long run. this is not the best solution.